# First "Revealing Module" implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, revealing-module-pattern

I have a little js I call a "jqGrid Factory" to encapsulate common settings and functionality across my web app.

I just want to see what improvements I can make.

```
 var jqGridReportFactory = (function () {

    var config = {
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            gridview: true,
            sortable: true,
            rowNum: 50,
            rowList: [50, 100, 200],
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: false,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            sortname: 'Affiliate',
            subGridSortname: 'SubAffiliate'
        },
        subGridOptions = {
            plusicon: "ui-icon-plus",
            minusicon: "ui-icon-minus",
            openicon: "ui-icon-carat-1-sw"
        };

    function createReport(gridOptions, optionalConfig) {
        $.extend(config, optionalConfig);
        //$.extend(gridOptions, gridOptions);

        var jqGridObj = {
            url: gridOptions.url,
            datatype: config.datatype,
            mtype: config.mtype,
            postData: gridOptions.postData,
            colNames: gridOptions.colNames,
            colModel: gridOptions.colModel,
            height: config.height,
            autowidth: config.autowidth,
            shrinkToFit: config.shrinkToFit,
            gridview: config.gridview,
            sortable: config.sortable,
            rowNum: config.rownum,
            rowList: config.computeHighlightColorsrowList,
            viewrecords: config.viewrecords,
            loadonce: config.loadonce,
            sortorder: config.sortorder,
            sortname: gridOptions.sortname,
            pager: gridOptions.pager,
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                reportLoadError('onLoadConversionHistory', xhr, st, err);
                unblockUI();
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                unblockUI();
                goToScrollPosition($('#reportPlaceHolder'));
            },
            subGrid: gridOptions.subGrid,
            onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                $(this).jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", rowid);
            }
        };

        if (gridOptions.subGrid) {
            jqGridObj = addSubGrid(jqGridObj, gridOptions);
        }

        //jqGrid factory go!!
        $("#" + gridOptions.id).jqGrid(jqGridObj);
    }

    function addSubGrid(jqGridObj, gridOptions) {
        var subGridObj = {
            subGridOptions: subGridOptions,
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {
                var affiliate = $("#" + id).jqGrid("getCell", rowId, 'Affiliate');

                var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
                var $subGrid;
                $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table>");
                $subGrid = $('#' + subgridTableId); //cache subgrid, more performant

                var subGridColNames = jQuery.extend({}, gridOptions.colNames);
                var subGridColModel = jQuery.extend({}, gridOptions.colModel);
                //change parent names from Affiliate to Subaffiliate
                //other than that subGrid model is exactly the same as parent Affiliate model for all reports so far

                subGridColNames[0] = 'SubAffiliate';
                subGridColModel[0].name = 'SubAffiliate';
                subGridColModel[0].index = 'SubAffiliate';

                //add affiliate to subGridPostData
                var a = { Affiliate: affiliate };
                $.extend(gridOptions.subGridPostdata, a);

                $subGrid.jqGrid({
                    url: gridOptions.url,
                    datatype: gridOptions.datatype,
                    mtype: gridOptions.mtype,
                    postData: gridOptions.subGridPostdata,
                    colNames: subGridColNames,
                    colModel: subGridColModel,
                    height: config.height,
                    sortname: config.subGridSortname,
                    sortorder: config.sortorder,
                    loadonce: config.loadonce,
                    //these subgrid setting should not be overridden in my opinion - Brian Ogden
                    autowidth: true,
                    shrinkToFit: true,
                    gridview: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    viewrecords: true
                    ///////////////////////
                });

                if (gridOptions.subGridHeadersHidden) {
                    //hide subgrid column headers
                    $subGrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
                    .hide();
                }
            },
            subGridRowColapsed: function (subgridId, rowId) {
                // this function is called before removing the data 
                var subgridTableId;
                subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t"; //
                $("#" + subgridTableId).remove();
            }
        };

        $.extend(true,jqGridObj, subGridObj);

        return jqGridObj;
    }

    return {
        createReport: createReport
    };

})();
```

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to show the latest of my refactoring of my jqgrid factory, I didn't renamed some of the options object members to camel case because I thought it was better for the users of this factory to match the option value that jqGrid uses:

```
var jqGridReportFactory = (function () {

    var constAffiliateStr = "Affiliate";
    var constSubAffiliateStr = "SubAffiliate";

    //default icons should be used for all reports so they not currently an option that can changed when using this jqgrid factory - Brian Ogden  1-24-2014
    var subo = {
        plusicon: "ui-icon-plus",
        minusicon: "ui-icon-minus",
        openicon: "ui-icon-carat-1-sw"
    };

    function createReport(o) {

        o = $.extend({
            //apply default properties
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            height: 'auto',
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            gridview: true,
            sortable: true,
            rowNum: -1,
            rowList: [50, 100, 200, -1],
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            footerrow: false,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            sortname: constAffiliateStr,
            subGridSortname: constSubAffiliateStr,
            subgrid: false,
            subGridHeadersHidden: true
        }, o);

        var jqGridObj = {
            url: o.url,
            datatype: o.datatype,
            mtype: o.mtype,
            postData: o.postData,
            colNames: o.colNames,
            colModel: o.colModel,
            height: o.height,
            autowidth: o.autowidth,
            shrinkToFit: o.shrinkToFit,
            gridview: o.gridview,
            sortable: o.sortable,
            rowNum: o.rowNum,
            rowList: o.rowList,
            viewrecords: o.viewrecords,
            loadonce: o.loadonce,
            sortorder: o.sortorder,
            sortname: o.sortname,
            pager: o.pager,
            footerrow: true,
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                reportLoadError('onLoad' + o.id, xhr, st, err);
                unblockUI();
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                if (o.rowNum == -1) {
                    $(o.pager + ' option[value=-1]').text('All');
                    //if loadOnce is true displays -1 
                    if (o.loadonce) $(o.pager + ' input.ui-pg-input').next().text('1');
                }

                if (o.loadComplete) o.loadComplete();
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                unblockUI();
                goToScrollPosition($('#reportPlaceHolder'));

                if (o.gridComplete) o.gridComplete();

            },
            subGrid: o.subGrid,
            onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                $(this).jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", rowid);
            },
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                var $icons = $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico");
                if (this.p.sortorder === 'asc') {
                    //$icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').show();
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc')[0].style.display = "";
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc')[0].style.marginTop = "0px";
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').hide();
                } else {
                    //$icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').show();
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc')[0].style.display = "";
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc')[0].style.marginTop = "0px";
                    $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').hide();
                }
            }
        };

        /*=================================================*/
        //Build subGrid
        /*=================================================*/
        if (o.subGrid) {

            /*=================================================*/
            //Check to see if subGrid colModel and colNames passed in, if not use Affiliate colModel and colNames
            /*=================================================*/
            var temp;
            if (!o.subGridColModel) {
                temp = $.extend(true, [], o.colModel); //deep copy array of objects
                temp[0].name = constSubAffiliateStr;
                temp[0].index = constSubAffiliateStr;
                o.subGridColModel = temp;
            }

            if (!o.subGridColNames) {
                //temp = o.colNames.slice(0);
                temp = $.extend(true, [], o.colNames); //deep copy not needed but better safe then sorry
                temp[0] = constSubAffiliateStr;
                o.subGridColNames = temp;
            }
            /*=================================================*/


            var subGridObj = {
                subo: subo,
                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowId) {

                    var affiliate = $("#" + o.id).jqGrid("getCell", rowId, 'Affiliate');

                    var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
                    var $subGrid;
                    $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "' class='scroll'></table>");
                    $subGrid = $('#' + subgridTableId); //cache subgrid, more performant

                    //add affiliate to subGridPostData
                    var a = { Affiliate: affiliate };
                    $.extend(o.subGridPostData, a);

                    $subGrid.jqGrid({
                        url: o.url,
                        datatype: o.datatype,
                        mtype: o.mtype,
                        postData: o.subGridPostData,
                        colNames: o.subGridColNames,
                        colModel: o.subGridColModel,
                        height: o.height,
                        sortname: o.subGridSortname,
                        sortorder: o.sortorder,
                        loadonce: o.loadonce,
                        sortable: o.sortable,
                        //these subgrid setting should not be overridden in my opinion - Brian Ogden
                        autowidth: true,
                        shrinkToFit: true,
                        gridview: false,
                        viewrecords: true
                        ///////////////////////
                    });

                    if (o.subGridGroupHeaders) {
                        $subGrid.jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                            useColSpanStyle: true,
                            groupHeaders: o.subGridGroupHeaders
                        });
                    }

                    if (o.subGridHeadersHidden) {
                        //hide subgrid column headers
                        $subGrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                        .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
                        .hide();
                    }
                },
                subGridRowColapsed: function (subgridId, rowId) {
                    // this function is called before removing the data 
                    var subgridTableId;
                    subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t"; //
                    $("#" + subgridTableId).remove();
                }
            };

            $.extend(jqGridObj, subGridObj);
        }
        /*=================================================*/

        //jqGrid factory go!!
        return $("#" + o.id).jqGrid(jqGridObj);
    }

    return {
        createReport: createReport
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your code, good use of the Revealing Module pattern.

I only have the following minor observations:

- `mtype` could use a better name ( I know, jqGrid uses it )
- `autowidth` -> `autoWidth` ( lowerCamelCasing )
- `gridview` -> `gridView`
- `rowList: [50, 100, 200]` could use a comment as to what it does
- `viewrecords` -> `viewRecords`( lowerCamelCasing ) etc. etc.
- `sortorder` -> Could use a comment with the possible values
- `subGridOptions` -> could use a comment with this URL : http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/
- delete uncommented code : `//$.extend(gridOptions, gridOptions);`
- You should seriously consider building `jqGridObj` with  `$.extend` out of `gridOptions` and `config`, cutting almost 20 lines.
- It is considered better to have 1 `var` statement with comma-separated variables instead of multiple `var` statements. ( in `subGridObj` )
- `$subGrid.jqGrid` could also probably be built with `$.extend`

Comment: Hi @konijn,thanks for your review,I was wondering,could you elaborate with a snippet of how I might build $subGrid.jqGrid with $.extend?

Comment: Oh nevermind! I understand what you mean by building $subgrid.jqGrid with $.extend now, instead of calling the function addSubGrid to build it I believe is what you mean

Comment: That's indeed what I meant, I guess you would extract your subgrid defaults into a properly named variable first.

Comment: I have made some improvements if you want to check them out.